# AWS fargate link containers Selenium grid

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium-grid, aws-fargate

I am trying to spin-up selenium grid server and attach firefox-node to it using fargate. I am using aws console for it since I am not that confident to write cloudformation. I want to link the two containers hub and selenium/firefox. In fargate default network mode is awsvpc and we can't use legacy 'link' parameter. And one of the tutorial video's suggested that two containers can communicate using local loopback interface commonly know as localhost/127.0.0.1. So my task definition is given below. But it still doesn't work. Any help is appreciated.

```
{
"executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"containerDefinitions": [
{
  "dnsSearchDomains": null,
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
      "awslogs-region": "us-xxxx-x",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
  },
  "entryPoint": [],
  "portMappings": [
    {
      "hostPort": 4444,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "containerPort": 4444
    }
  ],
  "command": [],
  "linuxParameters": null,
  "cpu": 0,
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "SE_OPTS",
      "value": "-debug"
    }
  ],
  "mountPoints": [],
  "volumesFrom": [],
  "image": "selenium/hub:latest",
  "disableNetworking": null,
  "essential": true,
  "links": [],
  "hostname": null,
  "extraHosts": null,
  "user": null,
  "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
  "dockerLabels": null,
  "privileged": null,
  "name": "hub"
},
{
  "dnsSearchDomains": null,
  "logConfiguration": {
    "logDriver": "awslogs",
    "options": {
      "awslogs-group": "/ecs/first-run-task-definition",
      "awslogs-region": "us-xxxx-1",
      "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
    }
  },
  "entryPoint": null,
  "portMappings": [],
  "command": null,
  "linuxParameters": null,
  "cpu": 0,
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR",
      "value": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    {
      "name": "HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_PORT",
      "value": "4444"
    }
  ],
  "volumesFrom": [],
  "image": "selenium/node-firefox:latest",
  "disableNetworking": null,
  "essential": true,
  "links": [],
  "hostname": null,
  "extraHosts": null,
  "user": null,
  "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
  "dockerLabels": null,
  "privileged": null,
  "name": "firefox"
}
],
"placementConstraints": [],
 "memory": "1024",
 "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxx:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
"compatibilities": [
   "EC2",
   "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-xxxx-1:xxxxx:task-definition/first-
  run-task-definition:10",
   "family": "first-run-task-definition",
  "requiresAttributes": [
 {
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
},
{
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
},
{
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
},
{
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
},
{
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
},
{
  "targetId": null,
  "targetType": null,
  "value": null,
  "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
}
  ],
"requiresCompatibilities": [
  "FARGATE"
],
 "networkMode": "awsvpc",
 "cpu": "512",
 "revision": 10,
 "status": "ACTIVE",
 "volumes": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `HUB_PORT_4444_TCP_ADDR = localhost`? I am using a different set of environment variables but setting the hub IP to localhost worked for me. Below is environment section of my task definition for Firefox container:

```
{
    "environment": [
        {
            "name": "HUB_HOST",
            "value": "localhost"
        },
        {
            "name": "HUB_PORT",
            "value": "4444"
        },
        {
            "name": "NODE_MAX_INSTANCES",
            "value": "10"
        },
        {
            "name": "NODE_MAX_SESSION",
            "value": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```